# HTML table column styling using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML table and I need a different styling in the last column:
https://jsfiddle.net/dqa9y1g3/

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

thead {
  border: 2px;
}

th.th {
  border: solid;
}

th.th3 {
  border-top: 1px dashed;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th">h1</th>
      <th class="th">h2</th>
      <th class="th3">h3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td>
    <td>r2c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the right way to do it?
This is what I want to get:
[image: Expected result]

Comment: You already have the classes needed to provide the border on your `.th3` items. One option is to simply add the `th` and `th3` classes to all elements in the table you want to alter.

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically need to target the last column, you can use this.
You also need to remove the table border, because it will be drawn over the individual `th` or `td` border.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

thead {
  border: 2px;
}

th.th {
  border: solid;
}

tr th:last-child,
tr td:last-child {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th">h1</th>
      <th class="th">h2</th>
      <th class="th">h3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td>
    <td>r2c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is wrong in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dqa9y1g3/1/) similar example, where css changes cell background color, but it's not affecting cell border style? @lupz

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:last-child` pseudo class selector. This works because those `td`s of the last table column are the last child elements of their `tr`s.

I also had to remove the border of the table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-right: 0px;
  /* border: 1px solid; */
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

thead {
  border: 2px;
}

th.th {
  border: solid;
}

th.th3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

td:last-child, th:last-child {
   border: 1px dashed;
   border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th">h1</th>
      <th class="th">h2</th>
      <th class="th3">h3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td>
    <td>r2c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach to using a `<table>` is to deploy **CSS Grid**.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.my-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 24px;
  gap: 1px;
}

.my-table-cell {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* FIRST TWO CELLS */
.my-table-cell:nth-of-type(-n + 2) {
  font-weight: 900;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* THIRD CELL */
.my-table-cell:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-top: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* CELLS ON THE RIGHT */
.my-table-cell:nth-of-type(3n) {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">
  <div class="my-table-cell">h1</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">h2</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">h3</div>
  
  <div class="my-table-cell">r1c1</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">r1c2</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">r1c3</div>
  
  <div class="my-table-cell">r2c1</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">r2c2</div>
  <div class="my-table-cell">r2c3</div>
</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://cssgridgarden.com/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/